# Python function/argument 'not defined' error

Tags: python, undefined

I'm very new to coding, and am working on an assignment in Python 3.5.2 and am getting a 'display_results not defined' error.  Am I placing it in the wrong section?
Thanks in advance.

```
hourly_pay_rate  = 7.50
commission_rate  = 0.05
withholding_rate = 0.25

def startup_message():
    print('''This program calculates the salesperson's pay.
Five values are displayed.
Hourly pay, commission, gross pay, withholding, and net pay.\n''')

def main():
    startup_message()
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    sales_amount = float(input('Enter sales amount: '))
    hours_worked = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
    hourly_pay_amount = hours_worked * hourly_pay_rate
    commission_amount = sales_amount * commission_rate
    gross_pay = hourly_pay_rate + commission_rate
    withholding = gross_pay * withholding_rate
    net_pay = gross_pay - withholding
display_results#<-----'not defined' error for calculations

def display_results(): #(parameters)
    print('Hourly pay amount is: ', \
          format(hourly_pay_amount, ',.2f'))
    print('Commission amount is: ', \
          format(commission_amount, ',.2f'))
    print('Gross pay is: ', \
          format(gross_pay, ',.2f'))
    print('Withholding amount is: ', \
          format(withholding, ',.2f'))
    print('Net pay is: ', \
          format(net_pay, ',.2f'))


main()
input('\nPress ENTER to continue...')
```

Comment: All the answers below will help you get past this particular error, but there are others that will manifest then. For example, in your function `display_results`, these variables are not declared `hourly_pay_amount`, `commission_amount`, `withholding`, net_pay`, `gross_pay`.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm still not able to get this program to run properly.  When I type this:   "display_results(hourly_pay_rate, commission_amount, gross_pay, withholding, net_pay)"

I now get this error: " display_results() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given"

I'm sorry, I'm so confused....

Comment: This error message says that the declaration of your `display_results()` method does not specify any argument (i.e. `0 positional arguments`), but you have called it like this, `display_results(hourly_pay_rate, commission_amount, gross_pay, withholding, net_pay)` (i.e. with `5 positional arguments`). Tip: Pay close attention to the error message; it tells you exactly what is wrong with the code if you take time to interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this very short program:

```
def main():
    r = 2 + 2

show_result

def show_result():
    print("The result of 2+2 is {}", format(r))

main()
```

**This program will not work!!** However, if you can fix all the bugs in this program you will have understood how to fix most of the problems in your longer example.

Here is an annotated solution:

```
def main(): 
    r = 2 + 2 
    show_result(r)  # Must indent. Include brackets and pass the      
                    # variable

def show_result(r): # Include a parameter list.
    print("The result of 2+2 is: {}".format(r))  # format is a string method     
main()
```

You need to indent and pass parameters to `display_results` and use the [correct syntax for format strings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). In your case something like:

```
print('Hourly pay amount is: {.2f}'.format(hourly_pay_amount))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this response.  Though I'm still trying to figure out how to fix your very short program...

Comment: I got it to work like this...

    def main():
        r = 2 + 2

    show_result(r)

def show_result(r):
    print("The result of 2+2 is: ", format(r))

main()

However, I'm still struggling with my original program..

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think you may still need to fix the string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

First, to call `display_results`, you need to provide an empty set of parentheses:

```
display_results()
```

It appears you have an indentation error as well, as it seems you intended to call `display_results()` from *inside* the call to `main`:

```
def main():
    startup_message()
    # ...
    net_pay = gross_pay - withholding
    display_results()
```

Without the indentation, you were attempting to access the name `display_results` immediately after defining `main`, but *before* you actually defined `display_results`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `display_result` is unindented. Correct the indentation and it should work

```
def main():
    startup_message()
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    sales_amount = float(input('Enter sales amount: '))
    hours_worked = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
    hourly_pay_amount = hours_worked * hourly_pay_rate
    commission_amount = sales_amount * commission_rate
    gross_pay = hourly_pay_rate + commission_rate
    withholding = gross_pay * withholding_rate
    net_pay = gross_pay - withholding
    display_results()#<-----'not defined' error for calculations
```

Comment: @AndrewL. there are many other things wrong in this program, but undefined error would go with this. His question was specific to `undefined error` and this solution would resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Indent and execute `()` the function.

```
def main():
    startup_message()
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    sales_amount = float(input('Enter sales amount: '))
    hours_worked = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
    hourly_pay_amount = hours_worked * hourly_pay_rate
    commission_amount = sales_amount * commission_rate
    gross_pay = hourly_pay_rate + commission_rate
    withholding = gross_pay * withholding_rate
    net_pay = gross_pay - withholding
    display_results() #<-----'not defined' error for calculations
```